# Problem with chartjs and react-chartjs-2 in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I tried to draw a line chart with temperature data, humidity data and brightness data. I tried to downgrade the version of chartjs and react-chartjs-2 but it doesn't work

```
type here Here's my dependencies and my code:
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^5.13.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  },
My code:
import React from 'react'
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const GraphElement = () => {

  const chartData = {
    labels: timeData,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Temperature',
        data: temperatureData,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
      {
        label: 'Humidity',
        data: humidityData,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
      {
        label: 'Brightness',
        data: brightnessData,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 206, 86)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
    ],
  }

  const options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
      },
      y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 1000,
          type: 'linear',
      },
    },
  };


  return (
    <div className='graph--container'>
      ĐỒ THỊ 
      <Line key={chartKey} data={chartData} options={options} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default GraphElement;
```

And i got this problem:

```
ERROR
"linear" is not a registered scale.
   
and 
Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused.
```

Please help me with this, thank you very much

Tried to change the version of chartjs and react-chartjs-2 but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever errors you are getting are from not registering the elements, we can do this will be below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import faker from 'faker';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);
```

code

[Line Chart sample demo on their website](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/line-chart)

When I implemented the same, I was not able to render the chart, I found that you set `linear` on your `x-axis`, in my example since data is not provided, I used string, so after removing linear, the chart got rendered!

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import './style.css';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const labels = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
  ];
  const chartData = {
    labels: ['test', 'test2', 'test3'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Temperature',
        data: labels.map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1),
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
      {
        label: 'Humidity',
        data: labels.map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1),
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
      {
        label: 'Brightness',
        data: labels.map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1),
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 206, 86)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        max: 1000,
        type: 'linear',
      },
    },
  };
  const chartKey = 'line';

  return (
    <div className="graph--container">
      ĐỒ THỊ
      <Line data={chartData} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6ytixg?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter)